# Deleting word from file evertime user enters a word to delete and writing the new array to a new file. C++

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Hello I am a beginner programmer and I need some help with a part of my assignment. The assignment is to make a menu driven program were the user can manipulatetheir file by:

1. Finding a word user enters and the line it is on
2. Deleting a word the user enters from the file using an array and write the new array into a new file. Every time  the user deletes a word from the file they write to a new file with the contents of the old file minus the deleted word. The 1st output file would be filename1.txt, then the 2nd output file would be filename2.txt and so on.
3. And finally replace a word entered by the user with another word entered by the user.

here is some information to help:

I am using  Microsoft Visual Studio

What has been covered in class so far:

```
-if, else if, else
-while, do-while, and for loops
-switch statements
-arrays, char arrays, and 2d arrays
-functions
-just started pointers
```

what has not been covered in class yet:

```
-haven't done vectors yet
-haven't done classes yet
```

Completed Tasks:

```
-Read from user File into a string array
-searched for word user enters with linear search
-replace a word deleted by the user with new word entered by the user
```

To Do Tasks:

```
In case 2 (delete a word from the file):
    -I need to get rid of the empty array element when I delete a word from the array.
    -let the user delete a word again, then save it into a new output file (ie: filname1.txt,fileName2.txt,fileName3.txt. etc)
    -Formatting code

create functions for everything I need, I can do this part i am just coding it without for ease of understanding
```

I mostly need help with switch case 2.
Here is the code I have so far for case 2:

```
case '2':
    {
        string d_newDictionaryArray[dictionarySize];

        cout << "Enter a word to delete: ";
        cin >> word;

        ofstream doutFile;
        doutFile.open("dictionary_deleted_word.txt");

        // copying from one one array to another
        for (int i = 0; i < dictionarySize; i++)
        {
            d_newDictionaryArray[i] = dictionaryArray[i];
        }

        // searching and deleting the word from the new array
        for (int j = 0; j < dictionarySize; j++)
        {
            if (word == d_newDictionaryArray[j])
            {
                d_newDictionaryArray[j] = "";
                cout << "The word " << word << " has been deleted :)" << endl;
            }
        }
        // Write to a new file
        for (int k = 0; k < dictionarySize; k++)
        {
            doutFile << d_newDictionaryArray[k] << "\r\n";
        }

        doutFile.close();


        break;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string space = " ";
int locate = -1;
for (int j = 0; j < dictionarySize; j++)
    {
        if (space == d_newDictionaryArray[j])
       {
            locate=j;
            break;
        }
    }
//to locate where the element with space is stored
if(locate!=-1)
for (int i = locate; i <  dictionarySize-1; i++)
    {
        d_newDictionaryArray[i] = d_newDictionaryArray[i+1];
    }
//to shift all the elements after the space to adjacent previous position
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly and I understand the logic behind what you did. Also how you located a specific element of the array will help me greatly in the future. The part that was really eye opening was initializing i to locate, I get so used to initializing i to 0 or 1 that I forget that i is just a counter and can start from anywhere, so this way all the elements after locate will be moved. Thanks again for the help!